# Loading multiple files into matrix using R

Tags: arrays, r, csv, matrix, import

I am new to the programming world and need help with loading a file to R and creating a matrix with it.  I can import individual files and create and individual matrix out of it.  How do I do this for multiple files?  I have 21 files that each contain 100 rows and 100 columns and I need to import each file and put everything in a single array.

Answer (score 6):

1. I would use `list.files` to list my files by pattern.
2. `lapply` to loop through the list of files and create a list data.frame with `read.csv`
3. `rbindlist` to bind all in a big matrix.

   ```
   temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
   named.list <- lapply(temp, read.csv)
   library(data.table)
   files.matrix <-rbindlist(named.list)
   ```

Comment: Where do I put in the file path to access the files I need?

Comment: @user2113499 you can set the path like this `list.files(path='your_files_path',pattern='.*csv')`

Comment: Or `lapply(temp, fread)`. One request has been to make `fread` accept multiple files and build this in.  So the 4 lines would become just `fread(list.files(pattern="*.csv"))`. That way it could check format consistency of all the inputs before starting to read them, so an error could be issued much earlier if the formats weren't consistent. It could also use less working memory by allocating for the full final big table just once. Rather than reading them all separately and then copying into the big one. Sound ok?

Comment: +1 @MatthewDowle yes it is OK !but what if the files are bigger than the memory you can allocated? it will be really good if  `fread`  can switch to something like `ff` package  to handle large datasets.

Comment: True but that's something different. `fread(<multiple files>)` would be better than `lapply(temp,read.csv)` in all respects. That's all I'm biting off for the moment. Data larger than RAM is for another day.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly clear what structure you want. You can choose between a 2100x100 matrix or a 2100x100 dataframe or a 100x 100x 21 array or a list with 21 entries each of which was 100 x 100. (In R an array is the term one would use for a regular 3 dimensional structure with columns all of that same type. (and then of course there is agstudy's suggestion that you use a data.table.)

In a sense agstudy's code already gives you the 21 item list of dataframes each of dimension: 100x100:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
named.list <- lapply(temp, read.csv)
```

To get 100 x 100 x 21 array continue with this:

```
require(abind)
arr <- abind(named.list)
```

To get the 2100 x 100 dataframe, continue instead with:

```
longdf <- do.call(rbind, named.list)
```

To get the 2100 x 100 matrix continue from the last line with:

```
longmtx <- data.matrix(longdf)
```