# Loop over directory to get Excel content

Tags: r, loops, xlsx

I have a directory with Excel files:

```
sites=list.files(pattern='[.]xls')
> sites
[1] "test1.xls" "test2.xls" "test3.xls"
```

This works:

```
a=read.xlsx(sites[1],14)
```

So I would expect that this would work too:

```
df=data.frame()
  for (i in sites){
  x=read.xlsx(sites[i],14)
  x=x[560:831,12:14]
  df=rbind.fill(df,x)
  }
```

However, that gives:

```
Error in loadWorkbook(file) : Cannot find NA
```

What is going wrong here?
Also, is there a way to vectorise this - the files are large and loading is slow; I can't use read.xlsx2 since the data are not in the right [tabular] format.

Comment: why not to save your files as csv and read them with read.delim or read.csv? you can't vectorize this. but you can use `rbindlist` from `data.table` to accelerate row bindding. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102499/loading-multiple-files-into-matrix-using-r/15102639#15102639)

Comment: The problem is that there are a few hundred Excel files [the example given here has just 3], so yes, converting them to csv would be easier and faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `i` iterates through the elements of `sites` and not the index. Try `for(i in 1:length(sites))` instead. Or `x=read.xlsx(i,14)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `ldply` from the `plyr` package.

I'm defining a function first because you want to take just a part of each file. If you were taking all of it, you could just use `read.xlsx` in the `ldply` call.

```
library(xlsx)
library(plyr)
sites=list.files(pattern='[.]xls')

fun <- function(x) {
  df <- read.xlsx(x, sheetIndex=14)
  df <- df[560:831,12:14]
}
```

Then use `fun` in `ldply`:

```
df.big <- ldply(sites, fun)
```

Which should give you a dataframe with all of your sheets combined.